# Is there any possibility of using query term in aws-sdk-php?

Tags: php, amazon-s3, laravel-5.1, aws-sdk, aws-cli

I want to know the size of the bucket and length of the bucket.For this i am  using aws-cli.iam passing below query from terminal.[aws queries link](http://cloudacademy.com/blog/aws-cli-10-useful-commands/)

```
aws s3api list-objects --bucket BUCKETNAME --output json --query "[sum(Contents[].Size), length(Contents[])]"
```

Iam getting the size and length.
Now i want to use this query in laravel php using aws/aws-sdk-php.but i think there is no --query term in it.Is there any possibility for getting count and length of bucket.

Answer (score 0):

The `--query` argument simply performs a [jmespath](http://jmespath.org/) search, so all you need to do is use the [jmespath php library](https://github.com/jmespath/jmespath.php).